# Buck converter after SEPIC converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, sepic

I have designed a SEPIC and Buck converter using the TI power designer tool, which I have individually tested, and proved to be working correctly. They are both of the non-isolated type, but when I use them after one another on the same ground the voltage drops fast very low to around 1V and steadily decrements to around 0.5V.

The specs are:

SEPIC: 12-22v IN, 13.8V OUT, 2A, 400kHz based on LM3488 (which I found is 14.5V OUT in reality so I have used a LM7812CV to drop the voltage)

Buck: 12V-14.5V IN, 5V Out, 2A, 698kHz based on a TPS563231DRLR

I have used my multi-meter to test the output, I have used a small LED as a starting point for my load.

From my basic understanding there should not be a problem using a SEPIC and Buck this way, when using the correct filtering for the high frequency switching noise coming out of the first. Which I have created using a Ferrite Bead. What could be the problem for the invalid voltage output? Perhaps I am missing something elementary as I am not lectured in EE.

[image: SEPIC]

[image: Buck]

[image: Overview]

Comment: can you post a schematic of what you have built?

Comment: You have not mentioned current and loads.

Comment: Show us schematics.  The LM3488 is an adjustable regulator, so you ought to be able to set it for 12V output without too much trouble.

Comment: Chances are high that you're drawing too much current with the second regulator.  Either just plain too much current, or too much inrush current.  Either way -- schematics.  The devil is in the details here.

Comment: The 7812 needs more drop-out voltage than 1.8 volts. Just replace it with a 1 amp diode and see what happens.

Comment: Because on nonlinear surge startup loads most EE’s fail to understand why you cant use a DC converter easily on Motors as the surge current is ≈100x no load max RPM current. a similar situation is true for Buck, worse Boost and Sepic converters Buck-Boost. The problem is the input impedance is not linear on startup unless there is a soft start mode so that V/I slope=Zin does not exceed rated load when you cascade. - that’s why you should make them parallel not series.

Comment: @wardn please edit the question to include a specific question. (you need to ask one question)

Comment: How did you do this: *I have used my multi-meter as load and to test the output*?

Comment: @Andyaka thanks for you comments, I will switch the 7812 for a diode and see what happens. I just measured the output using my Multimeter, and said it was my load as to note I did not hook up any other real "load". I have changed it again as I can understand the incorrectness of it.

Comment: But what did you measure?

Comment: @Andyaka I use a small 5V LED after the 5V Buck, and measure the output at the positive leg of the LED. Updating my schematic accordingly..

Comment: Out of curiosity, whats the point of using the sepic and then the buck? Do you need the 13.8/14.5V for something else?

Comment: @Beb00 Correct, I use the 13.8V for deep charging a SLA battery

Comment: Also, it seems pretty unlikely that the datasheet (or calculations from the datasheet) suggests that you should get 13.8V, but in reality you get 14.5V from a working system. It seems more likely that you have miswired something or chosen incorrect components

Comment: @Andyaka The drop in voltage (now 14.02V) does not make a difference here.